# Javascript timeout - how is value in function remembered?

Tags: javascript, timeout, closures

I have this function:

```
//We will store any failed subscriptions and retry them until the succeed (if ever)
addFailedSubscription: function(streamId) {
  failedSubscriptions[streamId] = true;
  $timeout(function() {
    failedSubscriptions[streamId] = null;
  }, 5000);
}
```

Is this safe? How is it that streamId is available to the timeout function after the function has returned? Is it effectively creating a closure for this function?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's a closure.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using JS [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).
Working demo below:

```js
var $timeout = setTimeout;
var failedSubscriptions = {}

var x = {
  addFailedSubscription: function(streamId) {
  console.log('streamId ', streamId)
    failedSubscriptions[streamId] = true;
    (function(id) {
        $timeout(function(streamId) {
        console.log('streamId ',id);
        failedSubscriptions[streamId] = null;
        }, 5000)
      })(streamId)
  }
}

x.addFailedSubscription(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be safe.
The *streamId* variable is in the scope of your *addFailedSubscription* function. Your $timeout fonction has the same scope that *streamId* even after the function return.
The $timeout function looks like a closure because it use a non-local variable in a local environnement.